# Why is Windows.Forms in System and not Microsoft?

Tags: .net, winforms, namespaces

I always had the idea that the root namespace in .NET, "`System`",  was mainly for stuff that didn't depend too much on a particular platform.

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas or insight as to why the `Windows.Forms` namespace is in `System` and not `Microsoft` since it seems to be fairly entrenched in one platform.

*(No flame wars or unnecessary MS bashing if at all possible please! :) )*

Comment: Actually Windows.Forms can also be used in Mono, and therefore also compiled for Mac OS X and $your_linux_distribution.

Comment: Don't worry about flame wars. That's pretty rare here. Those kinds of answers would be downvoted and lose interest pretty fast.

Comment: Interesting question - I'd also like to know how MS decide what goes in System and what goes in Microsoft. Too many things in System seem to be tied into Windows and too many things in Microsoft could work on alternate platforms.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I read somewhere that the `System.*` namespaces are for things that are part of the core .Net framework, whilst the `Microsoft.*` namespaces are for additional "value-added" optional extras, or things that are in development.

**EDIT:**

Brad Abrams has a discussion about it in his blog post [What Does that .NET Namespace Mean: System.* and Microsoft.*](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2008/11/16/what-does-that-net-namespace-mean-system-and-microsoft.aspx)

Additionally, a quote from *Visual Basic 2005 with .NET 3.0 Programmer's Reference*:

> The Microsoft root namespace contains Microsoft-specific items. In theory, any vendor can implement .Net languages that translate into Intermediate Language (IL) code. If you were to build such a language, the items in the Microsoft namespace would generally not apply to your language. Items in the System namespace ... would be as useful to users of your language as they are to programmers who use the Microsoft languages, but the items in the Microsoft namespace would probably not be as helpful.

This would imply that if I was to make a new .Net language, I would be able to make use of the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace to make UIs, but I would probably not have much use for classes in `Microsoft.*` namespaces.

Comment: Very good point! Never thought of it that way, but it indeeds makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be:

Microsoft envisioned the .NET framework as having the ability to be multi-platform, but they were only going to provide a runtime environment for the Windows platform. They probably assumed that anybody providing a runtime environment for another platform would implement it in such a way that System.Forms could be used. The runtime would handle the differences between the native implemenations.

Comment: Not particularly believable, considering how tied System.Forms is to User32.

Comment: Very true. I keep hoping that maybe the namespace was conceived before the implementation...and the implementation wasn't what they envisioned. Doubtful, I know.

Comment: @EFraim Not really. Sure, the implementation doesn't abstract much away, but that's not necessary when you're implementing your own runtime - you replace the whole thing anyway. But while the basic UI stuff is influenced by Windows, it isn't really *tied* to Windows (unless *you* use platform-dependent stuff, like overriding `WndProc`). Mono implements Windows.Forms just fine with whatever desktop manager you have on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Just because "Microsoft Windows" has been abreviated to "Windows" in doesn't mean that the "window" concept isn't wider than Microsoft.  All implementations of GUIs since the original IBM PARC interface through Microsoft Windows, X11 etc all refer to Windows and Form controls, it is just that Microsoft have called their particular implmentation "Windows".  Thus System.Windows.Forms seems correct as it is not necessary for a window to be part of "Windows".  Probably to it should be just windows with a lower case w.  But that would break the nameing conventions of the namespaces.

Comment: Actually Windows.Forms is specialized for the Microsoft(R) Windows look and feel, as opposed to GTK# and Cocoa#

Comment: Actually I think the reason you get the Microsoft(R) Windows look and feel is because you are using Microsoft(R) Windows.  See the answer by @adrianbanks.

Comment: When I compile Windows.Forms with mono in Debian Sid, I still get Microsoft Windows look and feel, similar to running Microsoft Windows applications with wine.